# Lubuntu LXQT emulate right click for touchscreen tablet

Tags: lubuntu, touchscreen, libinput, lxqt

I rescued an old tablet with Lubuntu 22.04.1 and most things work great with touch except for the actual desktop. I understand this is a difference between Gnome/KDE and LXQT - touchscreen options for LXQT are not as easily changed. So how do I get a long click or a two-finger tap to emulate the right click on the Lubuntu desktop, icons, start bar etc? (it works already in Chrome, perhaps because of the touchegg help)

When I look at the touchscreen settings via xinput or libinput, no scrolling or tapping options are listed under the touchscreen device. Can I just add these in the configuration file and they'll work?

Also, looking at Preferences -> keyboard and mouse -> mouse and touchpad, no device is listed for the touchpad (logical, as the touchscreen is not a touchpad). Can I somehow get the touch screen listed here so that natural scrolling, two finger scroll, etc can be enabled? (although honestly command line is easier for me but in theory this should be possible I guess)

Comment: You've not provided any release details; and I actually find your "*GNOME/KDE and LXQt*" a little confusing; all three are different desktops, KDE & LXQt are both Qt5 based where as GNOME is GTK3/4, but its unclear what difference you're alluding to.  It might also help if you're specific on what apps you're having trouble with, as GTK and Qt apps can differ, but you mention only 3rd party Chrome.

Comment: Apps are not the trouble; the destktop UI is. To be ultra-clear: long-click = right click on the desktop does not work. long-click = right click on the desktop icons does not work. long-click = right click on start bar and start menu (or whatever those are called) does not work. As a bonus, long-click = right click it the Qterminal does not work.